# Padding Array With Many Elements

Tags: c

I have 2 structures:

```
typedef struct
{
  int a;
} S1;

typedef struct
{
  S1[0xff];
} S2;
```

Let's say I only require the element 0xf0 out of S2->S1, and the rest will be zero or whatever, unimportant.

I fill the struct like such:

```
S2 g_s2[] = {
// 0x00
{ 0 },
// 0x01
{ 1 }
}
```

Is there some way to pad the first X number of elements so I dont have to type {0},{0},{0}, 200 times to get there?

Comment: Designated initializers: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html They are standard too: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S2 g_s2[] = { [0xf0] = 12 };
```

Here, we are initializing only `0xf0`th element to 12, remaining elements of the array will be zero.